# How can schedule to run 'deluge BT client' in ubuntu 12.1 using gnome schedule

Tags: gnome, deluge, automatic, schedule

Since it's a GUI there is bit of complication. Can you guys help? Thanks.
(I need a recurrent task btw)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already know how to create a New Recurrent Scheduled Task, so after you open that option, try typing: `deluge-gtk &` in the command section.

Then pull down the tab under command, place it as X application. Then in the Time & Date section, click on Advanced, put the time you want, remember that it uses a 24-hour clock so, say for 9PM you'd want to say 21:00 (that is put 00 in Minutes and 21 in Hour). That's it!

I use transmission to download between midnight and 6am, and this always works for me.